# liabru/jquery-match-height and absolute positioned image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For one of my projects i have used liabru/jquery-match-height plugin, to make 4 divs equal heights.
Those 4 divs has some text and image at bottom of text.
This plugin works well, no mather, what content is inside of this four columns, they have the same height and this looks good.

But, colums text differs, and images should live at bottom of divs.
So i make those images positioned absolute, and now, match-height plugin calculates heights wrong.

My question is, how can i take images into account, while calculationg heights, if those images are positioned absolute ?[image]